# Apps Script HTML Service Post request / sheet append limits

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a chrome extension that posts data back to a Google Apps Script app and I'd like to know if I'm going to hit any limits at Google.

The Apps Script app has a doPost function that takes the information that was passed across and uses appendRow to add the content to different sheets. Very similar to how forms works but allows us to deploy to users (via the chrome extension) and have a better looking UI.

We're wanting to push this out to potentially thousands of users and we expect a few form submissions a day from each of them. Should I be expecting to hit any set limits with this?

I've already taken a look at https://script.google.com/a/netpremacy.com/dashboard but don't see anything that would indicate any limits.

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no published limits at this time. However, the key thing to ask with apps deployed as web apps is that is the App running as you (the developer) OR the users accessing the web app?

If its running as the users, then you are going to be ok with the volume. The quota is fully debited to the end user.

If its running as you, then you need to worry about other quota first - does it send out lots of emails, does it create a lot of documents, etc.

The only exception to quotas is ScritptDb that always consumes the script developers quota.

Comment: The app does nothing but take the posted data and inserts it into a sheet. It runs as the developer, not the user. It doesn't create any documents, send emails. So this should be ok with regard to limits, right?

Comment: Sounds like it should be ok. Any reason you are not just using Google Forms to add data to your sheet? If you want to do something fancy you can write a onFormSubmit handler on a standalone form.

Comment: It's purely a UX thing. Making the form more accessible from an extension and making it more aesthetically pleasing we find we capture more regular and detailed feedback from users. Very similar to this: www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3845/quick-redesign-improved-feedback

If forms allowed CSS control i would have saved loads of time :)